# What is a “political caché”?

Tags: meaning

Somebody said this phrase in some political conversation on the radio, and I can't find the definition of what does the word *caché* mean in English.

If you search in the google books, you will find a lot of uses of the phrase without an acute accent. But it was pronounced as if it had an accent.

The dictionaries have the meaning of *cache* as *store of things*, but this isn't it.

The French word *caché* means *hidden* as a verb form.

- What does the word *caché* mean in English?
- Can it be used in the contexts other than *political caché*?
- Is *political caché* an idiom?

I think, the word means *behind the scenes*. But I couldn't find the definition.

[Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=MUdWAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA233&dq=%22political+cach%C3%A9%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIwomj2YXLAhVDxmMKHd8XCXQQ6AEILjAD#v=onepage&q=%22political%20cach%C3%A9%22&f=false) is where the term is used: *This was certainly an indication that her political caché still had viability.*

Comment: Please provide some examples of your word in the context of full sentences.

Comment: The example I found in the book with this exact spelling: *This was certainly an indication that her political caché still had viability.* (https://books.google.com/books?id=MUdWAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA233&dq=%22political+cach%C3%A9%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIwomj2YXLAhVDxmMKHd8XCXQQ6AEILjAD#v=onepage&q=%22political%20cach%C3%A9%22&f=false)

Comment: Good - that helps and it should be edited into the question. Comments are considered to be ephemeral on this site, and they are subject to deletion with little to no notice. The actual question *posts* and answer *posts* are treated with more care. (By the way, [Jeremy's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/308482/142322) fits the usage in your example.)

Comment: "Cachet", in the above sense (and as suggested by Jeremy), means prestige or credibility.  That seems to fit the quoted context.

Comment: "Cachet" fits the quote after the misspelling is corrected.

Answer (score 6):

There's a very good reason you couldn't find caché: It's because the word is actually [cachet](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cachet). In this case, it refers to "a superior status", which is the only way I ever hear this word being used. Someone with cachet is someone who can get things done, whose opinion is respected and whose wishes are obeyed.

Comment: I see, I didn't know this word. And pronunciation seems non-standard. What confused me is that one of the search results actually has *caché* with an accent. Thanks!

Comment: @GrammarAddict Words with french origin are sometimes pronounced that way, such as fillet.

Comment: Pronunciation of *fillet* goes both ways!

Comment: @GrammarAddict: it's entirely possible (probable, even) that you're not the first to make this mistake, hence the search result. (Which is one of the many reasons why [Google Is Not General Reference](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2374/google-is-not-general-reference).)

Comment: Without the entirety of the context of the speech/talk, you cannot jump to the conclusion that it's cachet/caché in the cachet sense. It very well could be a very French person talking English and saying the French cache word instead.

Comment: @Sakatox No, it was in the context of an American politics, talking about one of the personages in the upcoming elections. But I still wonder what would be a percentage of native speakers who would not understand this word.

Comment: This particularly irksome when talking to people about IT issues: they often confuse the pronunciation of the 2.

Comment: @Sakatox: The meaning is pretty clear. The French word *caché* means *hidden*, while the French word *cachet* means *cachet*. *"Political hidden"* doesn't make any sense. And the French word *cache* is pronounced differently.

Answer (score 0):

In such context, "cachet" proposed by @Jeremy would mean "charm", "character". I am not sure that this word matches with a political debate.

The expression is perhaps **political cliché**.

> For example: *The phrase ‘hard-working families’ is the most loathed
>   political cliché, according to the results of a new poll*. [[source:
>   Top ten political clichés revealed]](http://www.localgov.co.uk/Top-ten-political-clich%C3%A9s-revealed/38339)

Comment: It would? Where did you get that definition? It's not in [either](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cachet) of the [dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cachet) I checked.

Comment: @PeterShor - I was refering to one of the sense of this word (in French usage) having the best fit with the circumstances.